# Cant get cursor pointer to show on hover

Tags: javascript

On the onclick function I am having the issue of when I scroll mouse over the Read More text it doesn't show the cursor so you know its clickable. I have been able to do it by css with cursor:pointer but the issue I run into is all my elements after the first click on the page only open when I double click READ MORE. The first time I click any element it will open with one click but when I go to next element and click it takes two clicks. I appreciate any help I can get. Thanks

```html
<br><br>And all our treats are free from artificial colors and meet our standards for value and ingredient sourcing.&nbsp;&nbsp;

<span id="myBtn5" onclick="myFunction5()" style="color:#c44048;margin- 
    left:0px;cursor:pointer;"><em>READ MORE ▼</em></span>

<br>
<br>
<span id="dots" style="display: inline;"></span>
<span id="more5" style="display: none;">



    Every partner discloses the country of origin of every ingredient in each 
    treat, as well as how they go about sourcing the ingredient. We also make 
    sure that we partner with companies who we trust to find the best 
    ingredients for cats. 
    <br>
    <br>
    We ask Muddies’ cats to taste-test treats 
    before we commit to carrying treats in our stores. While we can’t guarantee 
    that every cat will love every treat, we hope with a little trial and error, 
    you’ll find something that delights your cat.

    <span id="dots" style="display: inline;"></span>
<span id="more5" style="display: none;">





    <script>
    function myFunction5() {
      var dots = document.getElementById("dots");
      var moreText = document.getElementById("more5");
      var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn5");

      if (dots.style.display === "none") {
        dots.style.display = "inline";
        btnText.innerHtml = "READ MORE ▼";
        moreText.style.display = "none";
        } else {
        dots.style.display = "none";
        btnText.innerHTML = ""; 
        moreText.style.display = "inline";
         }
       }
       </script>
       </span>
</span>
```

Comment: Why do you have a `script` tag inside of a `span`?

Comment: You can only have one element with any given `id`. This is **mandatory**. That why it's `document.getElementById()`, not getElement**s**. `id` is an **id**entifier, and **must be unique**.

Comment: jhpratt wordpress for some reason keeps adding that to my code.

Comment: change `if (dots.style.display === "none") {` to `if (dots.style.display !== "inline") {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/7rdqg38m/2/
This solution does require jQuery and CSS. This allows you to make a really clean and elegant function with toggleClass and of course allowing you to avoid in-line styling

index.html:

```
<br><br>And all our treats are free from artificial colors and meet our standards for value and ingredient sourcing.&nbsp;&nbsp;

<span id="myBtn5" onclick="myFunction5()" style="color:#c44048;margin- 
    left:0px;cursor:pointer;"><em>READ MORE ▼</em></span>

<br>
<br>
<span id="dots" class="hidden"></span>
<span id="more5" class="hidden">

    Every partner discloses the country of origin of every ingredient in each 
    treat, as well as how they go about sourcing the ingredient. We also make 
    sure that we partner with companies who we trust to find the best 
    ingredients for cats. 
    <br>
    <br>
    We ask Muddies’ cats to taste-test treats 
    before we commit to carrying treats in our stores. While we can’t guarantee 
    that every cat will love every treat, we hope with a little trial and error, 
    you’ll find something that delights your cat.

  <script>
    function myFunction5() {
        $('#dots').toggleClass('hidden');
        $('#more5').toggleClass('hidden');
      $('#myBtn5').toggleClass('hidden');
    }
  </script>
```

index.css

```
.hidden {
  display: none
}
```

Comment: That works but I don't want an alert box. I need  the hidden content to be revealed when clicked.

Comment: Updated - sorry the JS fiddle must have reverted to an older version.

If that happens again, please refer to the code in the answer above - it's working for revealing text when clicked.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. The issue I'm running into now is that I have multiple read more on one page for each article. I can click on any read more and it will work the first time, but when I go to the next read more on the same page and click it.. it takes two clicks to reveal content.

Comment: Can you please provide a JS fiddle or the code you're working with for multiple read more?

My suspicion is it's toggling all the classes and each time you click read more, it'll do it for all the sections. Ideally, a workaround is you can just rename the function and the classes to be unique. ie (dots1, more1, myBtn1, myFunction1) etc